# Как сделать экран quick help для Android?

Tags: java, android, activity

Существуют ли специальные библиотеки для создания таких экранов?

[image]

(это не реклама РокетБанка, просто что попалось из моих приложух на телефоне)

Или все надо ручками писать?

Comment: обычный ViewPager, помоему

Comment: [Вроде такой](https://github.com/worker8/TourGuide) библиотеки?